# I need to do copy-paste operation JsTree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I'm implementing a tree using jstree,i need to do copy-paste operation.But i'm not able to copy a node (parent with children) and paste it to one of its child node.I'm trying it using **jsTree-context-menu** plugin?Copy and paste are done, but its contents are not copied!?

### requirement

- Node 1

  - Node 2
  - Node 3
- Node 4

Assume this is my tree.I need to copy() Node 1 and need to paste under Node 2.I'm trying it using jstree-context-menu plugin and find its not working at all.

So my Result Must Be With content but content is not available.

- Node 1

  - Node 2

    - Node 1      <-----Pasted item

      - Node 2
      - Node 3
  - Node 3
- Node 4

This code for copy :

```
var inst = $.jstree.reference(data.reference),
    obj = inst.get_node(data.reference);
if (inst.is_selected(obj)) {
    console.log("\n<<<<---------copy---------->>>>\n");
    inst.copy(inst.get_top_selected());

}
```

This code for paste :

```
var inst = $.jstree.reference(data.reference),
 obj = inst.get_node(data.reference);
 inst.paste(obj,'last');
```

Guide me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please post an example of your code so that at least we know what you tried and try to undestand why it failed?

Comment: you need to provide more details about what you're doing

Comment: updated question.